# What's a good way to draw signals and systems diagrams as an instructor?

Tags: teaching

I'm a TA for an undergraduate signals and systems class. As part of my job, I need to prepare some homework problems. My co-instructors use Microsoft PowerPoint to make the diagrams, but I find it very difficult to use, since we need to copy/paste objects and carefully place them in precise spots. I'd rather write code. Is there some LaTeX package specifically for this purpose? Or, is there an alternate way to draw these diagrams? How do instructors typically do it?

Comment: i, sure as hell, am interested in the answer.

Comment: I was gonna suggest Tikz, as the guy answering [your question over at Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410225).

Comment: I use the Latex library TiKZ. See a related answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30300/explaining-communicating-spectra-generating-visualizations/30481), and examples of diagrams [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/).

Comment: As a student I prefer graphs and diagrams made with the TikZ library (easier to make and look way nicer than those made with other software).